# What is LyapunovSolve::meig message about?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra, warning-messages

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), a Sylvester equation $AX+XB=C$ has a unique solution for $X$ exactly when there are no common eigenvalues of $A$ and $-B$. But the following code gives me a message I don't quite understand:

```
A = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}];
B = Table[5 KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
c = IdentityMatrix[3];
LyapunovSolve[A, B, c];
```

> LyapunovSolve::meig: Matrix with multiple eigenvalues encountered. The solution may be inaccurate or may not exist.

Here `A` and `-B` will have no common eigenvalue. So I suppose the message refers to something other. I've tried looking for mentioning of eigenvalues in the documentation for `LyapunovSolve` (where `LyapunovSolve::meig` points unhelpfully anyway), but there the stability for $ax+xa^\dagger=c$ is considered only.

I've checked that the message vanishes if I break degeneracy of spectrum of `B` by adding `RandomReal[]` to its elements.

So what does this message refer to? Are there some special stability problems with this equation, not covered in the documentation?

Comment: "The solution may be inaccurate" - and this is the case. If `X = LyapunovSolve[A, B, c]`, then `A.X + X.B` will give an identity matrix with not exact zeros, but sth like `10^-16`. Contrary, if you simply take `A = RandomInteger[....]`, there will be no message. Rationalizing `A` helps.

Comment: I think it's complaining about the repeated eigenvalues of `B`. I don't know the underlying algorithm, but it must be a case in which the algorithm is sometimes numerically unstable. It's a warning that you should check the answer (which seems pretty good).

Comment: @corey979 I disagree. Consider `LyapunovSolve[N@DiagonalMatrix[{1, 2, 3}], DiagonalMatrix[{4, 4, 5}], IdentityMatrix[3]]`. It's complaining about a potential numerics issue. OTOH, an exact `A`, `B`, and `c` invokes an exact solver, which has no numerics issues.

Comment: @MichaelE2 That essentially illustrates my point: it complains when given approximate numbers. Changing to exact (via `Rationalize`, e.g.) allows to give an exact answer, so it does not complain. Or sth.

Comment: @corey979 It does not always complain when given approximate numbers. It complains when at least one matrix has inexact numbers and `B` has repeated eigenvalues. My point is similar (or complementary) to yours: *M* is warning, I surmise, that a numerical routine is being used that is known to be unstable on matrices with repeated eigenvalues.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think I get your point. Feel free to edit my answer if you want to add something :)

Answer (score 2):

Classically, a Sylvester/Lyapunov equation is solved via the [Bartels-Stewart algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/361573.361582). In your given example, however, the algorithm (suitably simplified in this case, since your $\mathbf B$ is diagonal) works without a hitch, so I suspect something else is being done behind the scenes:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42]; A = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}]];
B = 5 IdentityMatrix[3];
c = IdentityMatrix[3];

{q, t} = SchurDecomposition[A];
q.Transpose[MapThread[LinearSolve[t + #1 IdentityMatrix[3], #2] &,
                      {Diagonal[B], Transpose[c].q}]]
   {{0.0828636, -0.113095, -0.148619}, {-0.098646, 0.0380146, -0.0940719},
    {-0.161339, -0.157174, -0.103911}}
```

which is virtually the same as the solution obtained from `LyapunovSolve[]`.

If one wants a further check, one can do the (usually wasteful) reformulation of the Sylvester equation into a linear system involving Kronecker products:

```
Transpose[Partition[LinearSolve[KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[Length[B]], A] + 
                                KroneckerProduct[Transpose[B], IdentityMatrix[Length[A]]], 
                                Flatten[Transpose[c]]], 3]]
```

which yields the same matrix up to roundoff error.

Answer (score 1):

```
A = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}];
B = Table[5 KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
c = IdentityMatrix[3];
X = LyapunovSolve[A, B, c]
```

indeed gives the cited error, but

```
MatrixForm[A.X + X.B]
```

[image: result]

explains that the issue is that "the solution may be inaccurate". Contrarily, changing `RandomReal` to `RandomInteger` leads to no errors/warnings (showing that the repeated eigenvalues of `B` are not a problem here - the relevant theorem says that the eigenvalues of `A` and `-B` should be different):

```
A = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}];
B = Table[5 KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
c = IdentityMatrix[3];
X = LyapunovSolve[A, B, c]

MatrixForm[A.X + X.B]
```

[image: result of exact case]

Going back to `RandomReal`, if one `Rationalize`s the matrix `A`:

```
A = Rationalize[#, 10^-16] & @ RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {3, 3}];
B = Table[5 KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}];
c = IdentityMatrix[3];
X = LyapunovSolve[A, B, c]
```

it gives no warning, and

```
MatrixForm[A.X + X.B]
```

is also

[image: identity matrix]

For comparison:

```
MatrixForm[N @ A.X + X.B]
```

[image: numerical result]

Hence, `LyapunovSolve` seems to have some issues with the underlying numerics. With exact values, it gives an exact answer and does not complain.

Comment: Note that `A.X + X.B` ***is accurate*** to an error of `8 $MachineEpsilon * Norm[c]`, i.e. to machine precision less 3 bits error, which is not at all bad.